# Upload from camera and gallery is not working properly in all the versions

Tags: android, android-camera, image-uploading, android-gallery, android-camera-intent

I am trying number of tutorials and sample codes for take an image from gallery or camera then crop the image and upload it to server. I was implemented the code for that in that code am facing few problems the are.

1. In pre Lollipop devices when I crop the image using photos app the image is not getting reflected in image view but it's showing the message as image saved..
2. In nexus phone both camera and gallery is not working.
3. > 5.0 versions in few devices when I crop the image am getting the image like shown below [image]

below is my code snippet.`

```
public void getPhoto() {

        final String[] items = new String[] { "Take from camera",
                "Select from gallery" };
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, items);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("Select Image");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) { // pick from
                                                                    // camera
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    intent.putExtra(
                            "android.intent.extras.CAMERA_FACING",
                            android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT);
                    mImageCaptureUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment
                            .getExternalStorageDirectory(), "tmp_avatar_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg"));

                    intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            mImageCaptureUri);

                    try {
                        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_CAMERA);
                    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else { // pick from file
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    // startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_PICTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FROM_FILE);
                }
            }
        });

        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        dialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return;

        switch (requestCode) {
        case PICK_FROM_CAMERA:
            doCrop();

            break;

        case PICK_FROM_FILE:
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
            break;

        case CROP_FROM_CAMERA:
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                photo = extras.getParcelable("data");
                profile_image = encodeTobase64(photo);
                saveType = "photo";
                try {
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
                    obj.put("user_id", user_id);
                    obj.put("mode", saveType);
                    obj.put("photo", profile_image);
                    obj.put("is_profile", 1);
                    saveResponse(obj);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void doCrop() {
        final ArrayList<CropOption> cropOptions = new ArrayList<CropOption>();
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
        intent.setType("image/*");
        List<ResolveInfo> list = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        int size = list.size();
        if (size == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Can not find image crop app",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } else {
            intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);
            intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            intent.putExtra("outputX", 300);
            intent.putExtra("outputY", 300);
            intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
            intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            intent.putExtra("scale", true);
            intent.putExtra("circleCrop", new String(""));
            intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            if (size == 1) {
                Intent i = new Intent(intent);
                ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);

                i.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName,
                        res.activityInfo.name));
                startActivityForResult(i, CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
            } else {
                for (ResolveInfo res : list) {
                    final CropOption co = new CropOption();

                    co.title = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                            .getApplicationLabel(
                                    res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.icon = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                            .getApplicationIcon(
                                    res.activityInfo.applicationInfo);
                    co.appIntent = new Intent(intent);
                    co.appIntent
                            .setComponent(new ComponentName(
                                    res.activityInfo.packageName,
                                    res.activityInfo.name));
                    cropOptions.add(co);
                }

                CropOptionAdapter adapter = new CropOptionAdapter(
                        getActivity(), cropOptions);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Choose Crop App");
                builder.setAdapter(adapter,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                                startActivityForResult(
                                        cropOptions.get(item).appIntent,
                                        CROP_FROM_CAMERA);
                            }
                        });

                builder.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                        if (mImageCaptureUri != null) {
                            getActivity().getContentResolver().delete(
                                    mImageCaptureUri, null, null);
                            mImageCaptureUri = null;
                        }
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                alert.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
        Bitmap immagex = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        image_Array = baos.toByteArray();
        String imageEncoded = Base64
                .encodeToString(image_Array, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return imageEncoded;
    }
```

`

comment below before duplicating this question because i was checked a lot but didn't find any solution for this, please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: i was cleared the issue 3 by removing intent.putExtra("circleCrop", new String("")); from the code

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem last week and I finally solve it, it's a little bit different in my case I get an image in Base64 from a server then crop it

here's the code

```
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(imageJson, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap tmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
bitmapDecoded = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);

DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

int h = metrics.heightPixels;
int w = metrics.widthPixels;
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, tmp.getWidth(), (int) (tmp.getHeight()*1.6), true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(canvas.getCircleBitmap(resized, w,h));
```

imageJson is the image in Base64 it's a String I transform it in a Bitmap, after I get the size of the screen, the Bitmap resized is here for have a square image, cause I have a 16/9 image this is maybe not usefull for you, and finally I show the bitmap in an imageView and crop it with the canvas method getCircleBitmap

here is the method

```
public Bitmap getCircleBitmap(Bitmap bitmap,int width, int height) {
    final Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
    final int color = Color.RED;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect((int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.054), (int) (height*0.005), (int) (bitmap.getWidth()*0.945), (bitmap.getHeight()));
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
    bitmap.recycle();

    return output;
}
```

You can change the value of the rect for fit it for your usage
I declare this method in a canvas class who extends View, really hope this help you too and sorry for my english

Answer (score 1):

i also facing this issue..Now its working fine because i m using library

```
 **compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'**
```

public Uri mImageCaptureUri=null;

Pick image from gallery

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_FROM_FILE);
```

this is add to onActivityResult method

```
 //call this line after crop it 

   if(requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_CROP){
        handleCrop(resultCode, data);
    }

  case PICK_FROM_FILE:

            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            beginCrop(mImageCaptureUri);
            break;


private void beginCrop(Uri source) {
    Uri destination = Uri.fromFile(new File(getCacheDir(), "cropped"));
    Crop.of(source, destination).asSquare().start(this);
}
private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) {

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
       // mImage.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
        Picasso.with(SettingsActivity.this).load(Crop.getOutput(result)).transform(new RoundTransform()).into(mImage);
        mImageCaptureUri=Crop.getOutput(result);
        getImageUri(mImageCaptureUri);     //this method uri stored to sdcard
    } else if (resultCode == Crop.RESULT_ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(this, Crop.getError(result).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If user requests to take a picture:

```
 Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(BaseActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {
                            File photoFile = null;
                            try {
                                photoFile = ImageVideoUtil.createImageFile();
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            if (photoFile != null) {
                                imagePath = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imagePath);
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA);
                            }
                        }
```

If user requests to pick from camera you can use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_GALLERY);
                        dialog.dismiss();
```

And on your activity result you can get uri and use it:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fl_main);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            switch (requestCode) {
                case ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA:
                    if (imagePath != null && fragment instanceof PhotoView) {
                        bitmap = Tools.fromGallery(this, imagePath);
                        if (bitmap != null) {
                            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
                            ((PhotoView) fragment).onPhotoSet(bitmap);
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_GALLERY:
                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    imagePath = uri;
                    bitmap = Tools.fromGallery(this, uri);
                    if (bitmap != null && fragment instanceof PhotoView) {
                        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2);
                        ((PhotoView) fragment).onPhotoSet(bitmap);
                    }
                    break;

                case ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_VIDEO:
                    if (fragment instanceof VideoView) {
                        ((VideoView) fragment).onVideoSelected(videoPath);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Here the ImageVideoUtil Class which'll help you to crop, scale, save and read image video operations.

```
public class ImageVideoUtil {

    public static void startCameraIntent(Activity activity) {

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_CAMERA);
            }
        }
    }

    public static File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "SnapSense" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_IMGAE_SUFFIX, /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        return image;
    }

    public static File createVideoFile() throws IOException {
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "SnapSense" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        File video = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, /* prefix */
                ApplicationConstants.DEFAULT_VIDEO_SUFFIX, /* suffix */
                storageDir /* directory */
        );

        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        return video;
    }

    public static Bitmap decodeBitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
        try {
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, out);
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }
}
```

Finally here are some other static methods to help you:

```
public static Bitmap fromGallery(Context context, final Uri selectedImageUri) {
        try {
            Bitmap bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(context.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(selectedImageUri.getPath());
            int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            int angle = 0;
            switch (orientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                    angle = 90;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                    angle = 180;
                    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                    angle = 270;
                    break;
                default:
                    angle = 0;
                    break;
            }
            Matrix mat = new Matrix();
            if (angle == 0 && bm.getWidth() > bm.getHeight())
                mat.postRotate(90);
            else
                mat.postRotate(angle);

            return Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), mat, true);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError oom) {
            oom.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String getRealPathFromURI(Activity activity, Uri contentUri) {
        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
        Cursor cursor = activity.managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
```

I hope my code helps you. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue in Nexus. I used [Android Image Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) which is very lightweight and flexible.

compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.2.+'

Answer (score -1):

Each version has there own way to get path:
Try this method will work for every version, IT WORKED FOR ME:

```
public static String getRealPathFromURI(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/"
                        + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"),
                    Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{split[1]};

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection,
                    selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```